# Reading mail in PHP?

Tags: php, email, pop3

I'm using pop3class for retrieving mails from pop3 server. when I call

```
 $pop3->RetieveMessage($messageNumber,$header,$body,-1);
```

I receive header and body of the message in $header and $body variables.
when I

```
Print_r($body);
```

I've lot of HTML code in output. Can someone help me in which class should
I use for dealing with the received mail, because I don't know the returned 
data type of the mail.

Comment: Perhaps the email is an HTML email? :)

Comment: yes.. but how do I deal with mails in php? is there any special class?

Comment: Most emails are in MIME 1.0 format, so you would use something like `Mail_Mime` - http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this link can help u in getting the incoming mails

http://ca.php.net/imap

```
$mb = imap_open("{host:port/imap}","username", "password" );

$messageCount = imap_num_msg($mb);
for( $MID = 1; $MID <= $messageCount; $MID++ )
{
   $EmailHeaders = imap_headerinfo( $mb, $MID );
   $Body = imap_fetchbody( $mb, $MID, 1 );
   doSomething( $EmailHeaders, $Body );
}
```